# Timestamp '(seconds_since_epoch=1646303659642026800)' is not recognized in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a sql query in snowflake to load a csv file. Upon running, it's giving me the following error message:
Timestamp '(seconds_since_epoch=1646303659642026800)' is not recognized

Comment: A timestamp of 1646303659642026800 is represented as nanoseconds since epoch rather than seconds. A simple **select '1646303659642026800'::timestamp;** works fine for me, but it would be good to know how your query looks like and what kind of columns are you selecting.

Comment: How about including your SQL query in your question? It’s difficult to help you if you don’t provide any useful information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.